# My PID Controller in Java is not operating correctly

Tags: java, automation, pid-controller

I was looking for an implementation of a PID controller in Java and I found this one:

https://code.google.com/p/frcteam443/source/browse/trunk/2010_Post_Season/Geisebot/src/freelancelibj/PIDController.java?r=17

So, for what I could understand about it I am using it this way:

```
package lol.feedback;

public class dsfdsf {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final PIDController pidController = new PIDController(1, 1, 1);
        pidController.setInputRange(0, 200); // The input limits
        pidController.setOutputRange(50, 100); // The output limits
        pidController.setSetpoint(120); // My target value (PID should minimize the error between the input and this value)
        pidController.enable();
        double input = 0;
        double output = 0;
        while (true) {
            input = output + 30;
            pidController.getInput(input);
            output = pidController.performPID();
            System.out.println("Input: " + input + " | Output: " + output + " | Error: " + pidController.getError());

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

But he never stabilizes. He doesn't behave like a PID at all... This is the output I get:

```
Input: 30.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 90.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
Input: 80.0 | Output: 100.0 | Error: 40.0
Input: 130.0 | Output: 50.0 | Error: -10.0
```

Can someone help me tell me what I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, try with another set of PID parameters - for example 
*final PIDController pidController = new PIDController(10, 1, 0.5);*
First parameter is responsible for gain of the closed-loop system.
Second is responsible for eliminate fixed error on the output.
Third is responsible for dynamic of control.

Second thing - it is possible that real signal output is always out of limit, so it takes minimum/maximum value.

Thirdly, why do you always add 30 to output and assign it to the input?

Comment: I am just testing it. He should stabilize with an output of 90 (120 - 30), because the setpoint is 120 and the input is always output + 30.

Comment: Well, try with a lot of sets, for first you should test only gain part of controller, so the parameters would be for example (10, 0, 0).
Also a snippet of class PID Controller seems to be suspicious:
 // Calculate the error signal
            m_error = m_setpoint - m_input;
error should be calculated as follow:
            m_error_new = m_setpoint - m_result;
And once again, I really dont know why you add 30 in every loop. The output is changing (seeks to get a value of setpoint), so you'r code will always change also your input, and changing input makes changes on output etc.

Comment: I have tried all that. Well the input must change because this is a simulation, and if the input is always output plus 30 so the PID should stabilize at 90 correct? Since the output of 90 will equate 120 in the input, which is my setpoint for this simulation.

Comment: I will try to add that fix to the code. I really couldn't find any implementation of a PID for Java.